# Another definition for prime number

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

> How do you show that
>
> Let $n\in\mathbb{Z}^+$
>
> $n\mid (2^1+2^2+2^3+...+2^{n-1})$ iff $n$ is prime?

Comment: You missed to say $n>1$. However, the claim is not true in general.

Comment: @Dietrich Burde, If n is prime then indeed n > 1, unless I'm missing something ...

Comment: @ChiefVS  You've missed the edit. The comment was before the change. It said "if and only if $n$ is prime". The title still shows the original question (16:13:38 MEZ).

Comment: Ah gotcha... :p

Comment: I've reverted the question to *iff* because it's more interesting this way.

Comment: @lhf I agree. This was also the original question. Changing it after having an answer is not helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $2^1+2^2+2^3+\cdots+2^{n-1}=2^n-2$, one direction follows from [Fermat's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem): if $n$ is prime, then $n$ divides $2^n-2$.

The other direction is false by definition when $n$ is a base-2 [Fermat pseudoprime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat_pseudoprime): $341, 561, 645, 1105, 1387, \dots$ ([OEIS/A001567](https://oeis.org/A001567))

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**:  $2^1+2^2+2^3+...+2^{n-1}$ is a geometric series.

But $341|2^{341}-2$ even though $341$ isn't prime, so it should be **if**, not **iff**.

Comment: So what do you think about 'if'

Comment: Cf. [Fermat's little theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem)